# Dynamically calling a method in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I've seen users tackle this question before, like in thread:
[C# very dynamic invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836057/c-sharp-very-dynamic-invocation)

But I haven't had much success with the code given. I'm basically trying to call a method using some variable string.

Here's what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class _Model : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       string TargetMethod = "Index";
       Type t = System.Type.GetType("_Model");

       System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo = t.GetMethod(TargetMethod);
       methodInfo.Invoke(t, new object[] {});

    }

     protected void Index(){
       Response.Write("Index: Dynamically called!"); 
     }

}
```

On the view page, I should see the string "Index: Dynamically called!" written to the screen but I'm getting error:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `GetMethod` only returns `public` methods; add `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` and it should work.

```
var methodInfo = t.GetMethod(TargetMethod,
      BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

or to work for both public ***and*** non-public:

```
var methodInfo = t.GetMethod(TargetMethod,
      BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Also: it is an instance method, and you want to call it on the current instance, so:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] {});
```

Note the `this`, not `t`.

Comment: Still won't work because the arguments to Invoke are wrong. Instead of `t`, it should be `this`.

Comment: Also there is another error in his code. Should be `methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] {})`;

Comment: I added: System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo = t.GetMethod(TargetMethod,BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance); but now I get error: CS0103: The name 'BindingFlags' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Harvester316 so: resolve it like you would any other type. In this case, that is `System.Reflection`, so either add `using System.Reflection;` at the top, or explicitly use `System.Reflection.BindingFlags`. Also: just pressing ctrl+. will fix this for you *automatically* (giving you a choice of which approach to take)

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc. It's alive and kicking. New to asp.net.  I use notepad++, so ctrl+ won't work for me. By the way, not sure why my question got down rated. I guess I wasn't clear or too dumb for some people to be kind. Yikes. Thanks Marc!!

Comment: no problem; and the downvote can be quickly compensated by an upvote (like so) - the question is indeed reasonable